# Minimum Generators of Finite Groups vs. Subgroups

Tags: group-theory

For infinite groups (ex. Free Groups), a subgroup may have more number of  generators than the group. For finite groups, is the number of  generators of subgroup less than  number of generators of group?

[Of course, we understand number of generators to mean "minimum number of generators"].

Comment: Here's a counterexample (of minimal order!) on Vipul Naik's wiki, which is always good for this sort of thing: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Minimum_size_of_generating_set_of_subgroup_may_be_more_than_of_whole_group

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take any group that cannot be generated by less than $n$ generators, e.g. $\overbrace{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\ldots \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}^n$. Embed it into a symmetric group, e.g. by letting it act on itself by permutations. As you know, any symmetric group $S_m$ can be generated by two elements, a 2-cycles and an $m$-cycle. This way you get arbitrarily "bad" counterexamples to your question.